# Installing Packages in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, path, command-line-interface

I am trying to install Tensorflow so I can use it in Python but I am having nothing but issues. When I run 'pip install tensorflow' in the Command prompt I get the following error -
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBZGb.png)

I am new to this and I don't know what the PATH is. Can someone help with this please?

Thanks

I initally tried downloading python online bit for it to be recognised in command prompt it told me to install it from the App store, i dont know if this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: PATH is an environment variable in windows.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) You can follow the link from the error message to enable "Windows long path support".

Comment: I recommend sincerely you to learn some very basic linux. I know you may be relutant, but I say it for your best.

Comment: I’m not reluctant to learn Linux. How does that relate to my question?

Comment: You can try installing TensorFlow in conda environment. Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link to install Tensorflow.